# In R, is it possible to create a random list of words for a speech stream (exposure) where I give it the syllable triplets I need (psycholinguistics)?

Tags: r, cpu-word, linguistics

I am conducting an experiment in PsychoPy where I have various tasks such as the target detection task, familiarity rating task, and the 2AFC. Before the target detection task, I need to create an exposure phase. I have 2 languages with 6 trisyllabic words each, and I have 3 versions of each language meaning that I basically have 6 languages in total. I would like to put together triplets (words) within each language in a random order to then create auditory streams for the exposure phase (which I imagine would last about 6 minutes). I was wondering if there was a way to code for this in R? I am a beginner in the field of psycholinguistic research, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If you can describe the sampling method, R can probably implement it (or any other programming language). There's probably no existing function that does exactly what you want so you'll have to put the pieces together yourself. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. The question is kind of too vague at the moment to actually be answerable. Stack Overflow is not for general discussion.